# Cannot compile SDL2 with g++ MinGW

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, sdl, sdl-2

I followed the tutorial [here](https://w3.cs.jmu.edu/bernstdh/Web/common/help/cpp_mingw-sdl-setup.php)

the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* args[]){
    cout<<"Start"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

to run the code I use:

```
g++ Main.cpp  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows
```

and then I get the error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: try #define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED before including sdl. Also is the SDL dll in the same folder as your exe?

Comment: It solved to problem only for the code above but once i add SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO); I get the error: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'

Comment: I solved it by using the 32bit version of SDL (i have a 64bit os so idk why it didnt work)

Comment: were you compiling to 32 bit exe or 64 bit exe? note that Visual Studio defaults to 32 bit.